# How to add class to list in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class CCC {
  int num;

  CCC(this.num) : this.num = num;
}

void main() {
  List list = [];
  CCC c1 = CCC(10);
  CCC c2 = CCC(20);

  print(list);
}
```

I really don't know. A two-dimensional array is needed in conjunction with the db, but unless you use a class in the list, isn't there an array?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue you are facing while arching x result, please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting

Answer (score 0):

as your question is not clear what you want to ask but what I understand is you want to add class object in list.... For this you have can specify list type then add object of class to it. like,

```
class CCC{
  final int num;
  CCC(this.num);
}
void main(){
  // specify the list type
  List<CCC> list = [];
  CCC c1 = CCC(10);
  CCC c2 = CCC(20);
  list.add(c1);
  list.add(c2);
  // here you can print all items' property
  for (var item in list){
    print(item.num);
  }
}
```

I hope I understood your question right